# Is there a way to filter a Datatable on initialization?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a data table being rendered that is being filled with data from an ajax call, here is the code for this:

```
let table;

        table = $('#table_preview').DataTable({
          "pageLength": 10,
          "processing": true,
          "ajax": {
              "url": '/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php',
              "type": "POST",
              "data": { action: "getPesticidesForTable" }
          },
          "columns": [
            { "data": "crop" },
            { "data": "diseases" },
            { "data": "chemical" },
            { "data": "product" },
            { "data": "rate" },
            { "data": "max_no" },
            { "data": "hi" },
            { "data": "mrl" },
            { "data": "pcs_no" },
            { "data": "supplier" }
          ]          
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: "/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            action: 'getPesticidesForTable'
          }
        })
        .done(res => {
          console.log(res);
        });
```

My question is, is there a way to pass in a way to only show rows where "crop" is "Wheat" for example, without having to manually search. Obviously the end goal is to have it dynamic and filter based on what a user clicks on or pre-determines. I have looked through the datatable docs but can't seem to find anything as such

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after more digging:

```
"searchCols": [
     { "search": "Brussels Sprouts" },
     { "search": "Ring spot" }
 ]
```